# Exception during IR lowering in a simple setup, possible bug in compose?

Tags: compiler-errors, android-jetpack-compose

This setup strangely throws `Exception during IR lowering`, It got something to do with the combination of lazyColum, inner compose functions and `Modifier`

To reproduce the bug/error:

- step 1: create a composable function

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TheContent() {

}
```

- step 2: setup a lazy colum

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TheContent() {
    LazyColumn(
        content = {
            items(emptyList<Any>()) {

            }
        }
    )
}
```

- step 3: create an inner component as follows:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TheContent() {
    @Composable
    fun InnerContent() {
        Row { //Box, Row, Column, etc.
            Box( //Box, Row, Column, etc.
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f, false) //Error
                    .weight(weight = 1f, fill =  false) //Error
                    .padding(vertical = 1.dp, horizontal = 1.dp) //Error
                    .padding(1.dp, 1.dp) //Ok
                    .padding(PaddingValues(vertical = 1.dp, horizontal = 1.dp)) // Error
                    .padding(top = 1.dp, bottom = 1.dp, start = 1.dp, end = 1.dp) //Error
                    .padding(PaddingValues(top = 1.dp, bottom = 1.dp, start = 1.dp, end = 1.dp)) // Error
                    .padding(1.dp, 1.dp, 1.dp, 1.dp) // Ok
                    .padding(1.dp) //Ok
                    .padding(PaddingValues(1.dp)) // Ok
                    .size(1.dp) //Ok
                    .clickable {} //Ok
                    .border(
                        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(1.dp)
                    ) //Ok
            ) {
            }
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        content = {
            items(emptyList<Any>()) {

            }
        }
    )
}
```

- To this point nothing will be thrown and everything will be OK
- step 4: reference inner content inside the lazy list

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TheContent() {
    @Composable
    fun InnerContent() {
        Row { //Box, Row, Column, etc.
            Box( //Box, Row, Column, etc.
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f, false) //Error
                    .weight(weight = 1f, fill =  false) //Error
                    .padding(vertical = 1.dp, horizontal = 1.dp) //Error
                    .padding(1.dp, 1.dp) //Ok
                    .padding(PaddingValues(vertical = 1.dp, horizontal = 1.dp)) // Error
                    .padding(top = 1.dp, bottom = 1.dp, start = 1.dp, end = 1.dp) //Error
                    .padding(PaddingValues(top = 1.dp, bottom = 1.dp, start = 1.dp, end = 1.dp)) // Error
                    .padding(1.dp, 1.dp, 1.dp, 1.dp) // Ok
                    .padding(1.dp) //Ok
                    .padding(PaddingValues(1.dp)) // Ok
                    .size(1.dp) //Ok
                    .clickable {} //Ok
                    .border(
                        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(1.dp)
                    ) //Ok
            ) {
            }
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        content = {
            items(emptyList<Any>()) {
                InnerContent()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Now, the problem starts.

- note: the modifier of the top level composable call in the inner composable function is not effected.
- note: if the call was outside lazyList, the compiler will not complain.
- node: if the inner composable function was not an inner composable, the compiler will not complain.
- note: if the inner composable function was inside an inner class, the compiler will not complain.

---

My Questions are:

- if this is a bug or I haven't understood compose correctly
- if it was a bug, then is it fixed yet, will be fixed shortly, will be fixed later, or will never be fixed.
- also, an explanation of why this is happening?

---

[Full Stacktrace/ Compiler log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LSafer/drive/master/stacktrace.txt)

Comment: I got a workaround for that using lambdas: `val InnerContent: @Composable ()->Unit = { /* ... */  }`

Comment: Well excellent question sir, and I will share my knowledge with you. What I get from what you described so learnedly in your question, is that there is a problem. I also kinda think you want the solution for that, but not quite sure about that. Please elaborate more will you? Thanks, with all due regards.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you so well. I am not a native speaker. In conclusion, I faced this problem while I was trying to optimize an application's code. When I faced this problem, I tried to capture the cause of the problem. Then, I know that this issue might be a bug. So, I posted this question to know if it was a bug or not and if not then whats the error and if so then how and when the fix will be available.

Comment: btw, I am really convened now that this is a bug. because if compose can handle lambda functions then it must handle functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's a bug, I don't think it should be fixed. Compose isn't meant to be used like that

You should declare composable functions only on the top file level

If you need to reuse part of composable inside one file just make it private, like this:

```
@Composable
fun TheContent() {
    LazyColumn(
        content = {
            items(emptyList<Any>()) {
                InnerContent()
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
private fun InnerContent() {
...
}
```

Why is that? Because embedding composables on into an other makes code much less readable

Comment: I first tried to do that, but I work in a company and creating functions for each component will make the file full of functions with no applicable naming scheme

Comment: So, because its easier to create a function for each component and to not fill the file with so much functions. I think the best way is inner/local functions.

Comment: Right now, I found a workaround by using lambdas! :)

Comment: @LSafer ofc it's up to you, but when you're using inner function you're giving it a name too. If you split your views by many files, you'll have no problem having same name `@Composable private Cell()` in each file, same as you're doing with local functions. Each time you think an inner function if needed - just create a new file with one main function and many privates

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I cracker a terrible joke. Well, seriously, I do appreciate the extent of background you have provided. I have seen many questions (unanswered) on the site, revolving around IR lowering, but nobody seems to have experimented like that. The observations are brilliant, will definitely allow experts to provide a viable solution.